# google drive api v2/v3: Are exportLinks and File.export the same?

Tags: google-drive-api

The description of Files.export says "Exports a Google Doc to the requested MIME type and returns the exported content. Please note that the exported content is limited to 10MB."

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export

When running Files.get, the metadata contains a list of "exportLinks" as a link to export the file in multiple formats.

So my question is are these exportLinks different than doing File.export? Do the exportLinks urls have a 10MB limit?

Answer (score 1):

`exportLinks` does not have a 10MB limit. You'll notice this if you try to try to export a larger-than-10MB file through one of the export links. It will be exported successfully, while using [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) will result in a `403` error with the message: `"This file is too large to be exported."`.

Apart from this limitation, I don't think there is a difference between a file exported via `Files: export` and one exported through one of the `exportLinks`, as long as the same MIME type is specified.

#### Reference:

- [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)
- [G Suite documents and corresponding export MIME types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats)

Comment: Thanks for the info.

I tried to test to see if I could download a file larger than 10mb, but I only had credentials for client drives and couldn't control the target file's size.

Comment: @SamLehman You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer that has been helpful to you, since the community relies on this to share knowledge to other users.